# How do I get the filename of my launched file without extension / directory?

Tags: vb.net

How do I find the current name of my launched vb.net project without listing the directory or extension?

I've searched for other solutions, but all of them either has the extension at the end, and/or the directory location at the start, I just want the plain file name, no extension, no directory.

Example:

```
    Dim Filename as string = (code that finds the file name)
    MsgBox(Filename)
```

Which would output `Test` as for this example the program was named `Test.exe`

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Name`

Comment: @T.S. Name wasn't apart of assembly, I then tried `.FullName` instead which just gave the assembly name along with version and other information while it's the executable filename im looking for (if the user changes the name etc). Thanks though!

Comment: you wanted the name of the exe or the name of the DLL where the code is? `IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` return the name of the DLL if the code is not executed by the main executable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a WinForms app:

```
Dim fileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at this one?

```
Dim PathofYourFile As String = "c:\MyDirectory\MYFile.txt"
Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(PathofYourFile)
MsgBox(FileName)
```

Comment: That just gave me the extension .txt while it's the filename i'm looking for, thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

```
Public Class FOL

Dim MyFileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath)

Private Sub FOL_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If MyFileName.Equals("fol") Then
        Updater.Show()
    End If 
End Sub
End Class
```

This example opens defined form "Updater" before loads main form.